# Handle Exception after all lines have been finished execution without finally

Tags: java, exception

I need methodA2 also gets executed even though there is an exception by methodA1(). Here I have added only two methods as methodA1() and methodA2(). Let's say there are many methods. In that case also, the solution should be able to applicable.

```
        class A {
             String methodA1() throws ExceptionE {
                // do something
            }

            String methodA2() throws ExceptionE {
                 // do something
            }
        }

        class C extends A {
                String methodC() throws ExceptionE2 {
                try {
                    methodA1();
                    methodA2();
                } catch (ExceptionE e) {
                     throw new ExceptionE2();
                }
            }
        }
```

Please note that there can be many methods invoked with methodA1, methodA2. In that case having multiple try, catch, finally will look ugly.. So are there any other methods to do that?

I need to store error information in a log file. In methodA1(), methodA2() ... information in each tag is get validated. what I want is having all the error information in log file. Once exception throws it will generate log file. So I will miss validation information from other tags. So we can't go for finally approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop with Java 8 lambdas:

```
interface RunnableE {
    void run() throws Exception;
}

class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<RunnableE> methods = Arrays.asList(
                () -> methodA1(),
                () -> methodA2(),
                () -> methodA3()
        );

        for (RunnableE method : methods) {
            try {
                method.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // log the exception
            }
        }
    }

    private static void methodA1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("A1");
    }

    private static void methodA2() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("A2");
    }

    private static void methodA3() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("A3");
    }

}
```

Please note that the interface is needed only when methods throw checked exception. If they were throwing only runtime exceptions, you could use `java.lang.Runnable` instead.

Comment: Can't use `Runnable` since it won't allow checked exceptions. Note that OP is throwing checked exception named `ExceptionE`, listed in `throws` clause of methods.

Comment: @Andreas declaring `throws` clause doesn't mean that it is checked exception, you can also use it for runtime exception :) Anyway, thanks for pointing it out, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No other way. If each method can throw exception, but you want to continue execution of remaining methods anyway, then each method call must be in its own `try-catch` block.

Example:

```
List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    methodA1();
} catch (Exception e) {
    exceptions.add(e);
}
try {
    methodA2();
} catch (Exception e) {
    exceptions.add(e);
}
try {
    methodA3();
} catch (Exception e) {
    exceptions.add(e);
}
if (! exceptions.isEmpty()) {
    if (exceptions.size() == 1)
        throw exceptions.get(0);
    throw new CompoundException(exceptions);
}
```

You will of course have to implement the `CompoundException` yourself.